# How to compare 2 rows and display the differences?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access-2010

I have 1 table with dozens of possible combinations "ROWS".

1. the user will be asked to enter two search terms
2. after that the query is executed and display the 2 matching rows as results

How can I compare the 2 queried rows and display the differences for each column as an "alternate field"?

How can I make sure the user gets prompted to enter the 2 search terms?
The query below works when I enter it as shown, but I can't figure out how to prompt twice:

```
Select
  [100_Prts].*
From
  [100_Prts]
Where
  ([100_Prts].[T101_PART] = '6-HPB01A') Or
  ([100_Prts].[T101_PART] = '8-H01S7')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in Access:

```
SELECT [100_Prts].*
FROM 100_Prts
WHERE ((([100_Prts].T101_PART)=[Enter Part Number])) OR ((([100_Prts].T101_PART)=[Enter Alternative Part Number]));
```